# Solrj Query Dynamic Field

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

In Solrj (Solr 3.6), am I able to filter my search for a dynamic field:

```
params.set("fl", "name*_s");
```

Or do I [still](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/fl-parameter-and-dynamic-fields-td489832.html) need to copy this field to a new field (non-dynamic) in order to search it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> params.set("fl", "name*_s");

I don't think you can do this in 3.6. At least, [the patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2444)  is labelled as "Fix Version/s: 4.0"

Now, you can still retrieve a value from a specific dynamic field, like "name123_s" by naming it directly.

But I'm not sure if I'm answering the right question, as "fl" isn't involved in filtering, or searching. "fl" is the list of stored fields to return.

If you want to search multiple fields, you should look at the "qf" parameter of the edismax query parser.